# Vue pass data from compontent 1 to a method in component 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a parent component and a childcomponent.
In my parent component I call a simple childcomponent-method to save an email to the `email` variable. But the variable `email` does not change.

My **Parentcomponent**:

```
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

export default {

  components: {ChildComponent},

  methods: {
    openDocument(d) {
      ChildComponent.methods.saveEmail('new@example.com');
  }
}
```

My **Childcomponent**:

```
<template>
  <div>
    Email: {{ email }}
  </div>

</template>

<script>


export default {

  data: function () {
    return {
      email: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveEmail(email) {
      this.email = email; // this does NOT change my email variable
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

Why my `email` variable does not change? How can I change this variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vue it is not work like that. You have to use Probs:

Parent :

```
<template>

    <div class="container">
        <child-component :email ="email"></child-component>   // NEW HERE
    </div>

</template>

<script>

import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

module.exports = {

    data: function () {
        return {
            email:''
        }
    },

   methods: {
      openDocument(d) {
           this.email = "example@gmil.com"
      }
    },
}
</script>
```

Child component:

```
<template>

<div class="container">
    <h1>Profile Form Component</h1>
</div>  

</template>


<script>


module.exports = {


module.exports = {   
  props: ['email'], //NEW HERE

  created: function () {
    
    console.log(this.email) //prints out an empty string
  }
}

</script>
```

**ATTENTION**

As you I added 2 comment `NEW HERE` in the code , these 2 lines are really important for what you wanna do.

The code that I giving you is an example (not a complete answer) , Probs is the solution of what you asked for.

Hope it Helps <3.

Answer (score 0):

The `ChildComponent` variable only holds the `recipe` for creating components of this type - but it does not hold your actual component. Your actual component lives inside your template - you have to add a `ref` attribute to it (e.g. `<custom-component ref="custom" ... />`) and then reference it like `this.$refs.custom.saveEmail()`